# react-native-udp Packet not sent until other packets are received

Tags: react-native, sockets, udp, dgrams

I'm using react-native-udp for a real Time application in react native. But application after send a few packets, stops sending packets. Because it can't receive some packets. and may be because of the port in use.
I can't set timeout for receiving msg from server. react-native-udp use Nodejs Dgram socket for this.
Any solutions to fix this problem?

```
a = dgram.createSocket({
 type: 'udp4',
 reusePort: port,
}, function(error){
  alert("error in create socket:" + error)
});

a.on('listening', function() {
   a.unref()
})

a.send(msgArray, 0, msgArray.length, port, ip, function(err) {
      if (err) {
           alert("Error in  send: " + JSON.stringify(err));
           a.close()
           reject(false)
       }
});

a.on('message', function(data, rinfo) {
       a.close()
       resolve(data)
});
```

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: @trighati Sure, I edited my question.